# Access minio bucket through minio client from

Tags: minio

I have Minio operator installed on Kubernetes cluster. I am trying to `mc alias set` for minio in distributed mode.

I understand that for single node minio we use the command:

```
mc alias set ALIAS HOSTNAME ACCESS_KEY SECRET_KEY
```

I was wondering how do I set this for distributed mode as we will be having tenants layer above the bucket. To be more specific,my final goal is  `mc cp` to copy object to bucket of minio in distributed mode after configuring  `mc alias set`